# Copy List of Structures to Excel Range

Tags: vb.net, excel, list, structure

Does anyone know how to copy a VB.Net list of structures to an Excel range?  It's not hard to do with an array, but I can't get a list of structures to work.

Example:

```
Structure MyStruct  
    Dim MyField1 as String  
    Dim MyField2 as Integer  
End Structure  

Dim MyList As New List(Of MyStruct)  
...populate list of structures...  

Dim rng as Excel.Range = MySheet.Range("A1","B9")  
rng.??? = MyList  '*** This is where I get stuck. ***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With custom structures, iterating is the only way. You can't expect excel to be clever enough to map a list of structures with multiple fields into rows and columns.

```
Dim oneMyStruct, i as Long
i = 1
For each oneMyStruct in MyList
   rng.cells(i, 1) = oneMyStruct.MyField1
   rng.cells(i, 2) = oneMyStruct.MyField2
   i = i + 1
next oneMyStruct
```

Comment: Thanks, Alain.  That's sort of what I figured, but just on the off-chance that it *could* be done....  ;)